# Discrete Binomial question probability that one component does not work

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> The probability that a component passes quality assurance tests is
>   0.92. Twelve components are selected at random. What is the probability that at least eleven out of the twelve pass quality
>   assurance tests?

Given the question above, I attempted it like this: I found out the probability of one components not working, and subtraction from all components which are working.

P(1 component not working) =$\binom{12}{1}\cdot0.08^1\cdot(1-0.08)^{11} = 0.384$

So the probability of 1 working is $1-0.38 = 0.62$

Is this correct?

Comment: You've calculated the probability that exactly $1$ is non-working.  You also need to include the case that exactly $0$ is non-working (i.e. all $12$ are working), because that also satisfies "at least $11$ are working".

Comment: Thanks I was close but needed clarification Happy Christmas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! You've made a small mistake though, which even @antkam forgot to mention. With your method, using the complement won't yield the right answer, since, if we **let X be the number of components which failed QA tests**;

- $X\sim B(12, 0.08)$
- P(**At least 11 components passed** QA tests) = P(**At most 1 component failed** QA tests)

So by that logic, the probability you're looking for is $P(x\leq1)=P(x=0)+P(x=1)$, and NOT $1-P(x=1)$.

Merry Christmas! :)